# Android listen to touch release

Tags: java, android, touch-event, ontouchlistener

I'm trying to listen to a touch release but the event is not being fired.

This is my code:

```
public class MyView extends View {
    public MyView(final Context context) {
        super(context);
        setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
                if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    makeToast("press", context);
                } else if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                    makeToast("release", context);
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    void makeToast(String s, Context c) {
        CharSequence text = s;
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(c, text, duration);
        toast.show();
    }

}
```

The activity class:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MyView v = new MyView(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(v);
    }
}
```

What it happens is that when I touch the screen, a toast with "press" written in it appears, but when i release the touch, no toast appears, while i'm expecting a toast with "release" written in it to appear.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return true instead of false inside your onTouchListener.

What happens is that the Action Down was triggered first but you returned false meaning that Action Down was not handled.

If you return true, it will ensure that each action that it catches is handled fully, you would return false only if you knew some other view needed to handle the action instead.

Good Luck!